# Maintaining the checked status of checkboxes with localStorage

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox, local-storage

I'm trying to make a checklist without jQuery, of which the .checked status of each checkbox is saved in localStorage, so that it can be maintained when the browser or even the computer is restarted.

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/mzwawcjk/)

To achieve this, I've written three functions:

- `saveStatus()`, to save the current status of all checkboxes to localStorage. Activated by a button onclick.
- `loadStatus()`, to load the saved status from localStorage. Activated onload in the body tag.
- `clearAllInputs()`, to clear localStorage. Activated by a button
  onclick.

I couldn't find a better workaround for localStorage only accepting ("String","String") key-value pairs.

When I check a couple of the checkboxes and hit the save button, it just seems to refresh the page and all checkboxes are unchecked. Same thing happens when I hit the clear button.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's where JSON comes in. You can have an object or array store the states of your checkboxes. Once you save to `localStorage`, use `JSON.stringify` on the object to turn it to a string. Then save that string to `localStorage`. Reading goes the other way around, by reading the string from `localStorage` then use `JSON.parse` to turn the string back to an object or array for use on the checkboxes.